# Calculating percentage of polygons within specific areas using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.2, vector

I have a parcel layer and I am trying to determine the percentage of each parcel that falls within specific zones.  I tried tabular intersect but it just returned an empty output.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: please edit your original question with the edit button to ask a specific question. any suggestions won't get you much response. If you can add a screen shot example also.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Are the projections of the parcel and zone layers the same? What fields are you using in the Tabulate Intersection tool?

Answer (score 4):

Do the following:

1. add field "OldArea" to the parcels and populate with area values (Field right click - Calcualte Geometry)
2. Perform Intersect with the Zones dataset
3. add another field ("NewArea") and populate with areas after intersection (same way than #1)
4. calculate the percentage = (NewArea/OldArea) * 100 in the new field